# Sorcery methods are not available in RESTFULL web services grapes file rails 4

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, restful-authentication, grape-api, sorcery

How can i access rails sorcery methods in my RESTFULL API File.

desc 'Signin'
    post "signin_api" do

```
  if @user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
      @user.set_authentication_token
      @current_user = User.find(@user)
      status 200
      debugger
     # login(params[:email], params[:password])
     #login_user(@user)
     current_user
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not using Grape, I was running into a similar issue of Sorcery methods not being recognized in a Rails 5.2 api.

Adding   `include Sorcery::Controller` to the top of my SessionsController resolved my issue.

Example:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      include Sorcery::Controller

      def create 
       @user = login(params[:email], params[:password])
       .
       .
       .
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Source: [Last response in Sorcery issues #47](https://github.com/Sorcery/sorcery/issues/47)